# Is it possible to use google address search bar on the website

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to use the google address search on my website something like this:
[image]

But after spending a lot of hours couldn't figure out how to do it. I tried to use the API but it returns just geocoded value. I want to see that one I started typing first letters it would show me some first results. I know that I can use jquery autocomplete control for this target but also I need to know which api method is supposed to use for this target. Please help.

Comment: Enjoy http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete?hl=en-us

Comment: Thank you!!!! :) Please set it as an answer I will mark it is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps JavaScript API v3 [Places Autocomplete Documentation](http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete?hl=en-us)